# Bluetooth LE iOS - how to find only nearest devices with scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:

Tags: ios, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am trying to control the LE BT signal strength when scanning for peripherals.
The problem is when I have many peripherals nearby, I want to detect only the nearest to me. 
I am using

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:
```

Can I lower the device's BT power so the scan will show me only the nearest devices ? 
I am trying to filter the far peripherals with the RSSI parameter, but it is not consistant.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. The only limitation is to search for a peripheral with a certain service.
It's up to you to connect only the nearest peripheral.

Comment: RSSI is just an indication. Many parameters enters (wall, etc.) that can alter it. I think that why you can't filter by RSSI without doing a personal filter.

Comment: @Larme That's true. Often the RSSI value is negative, so the less negative the RSSI value the nearer is the peripheral. I thought this fact is clear to Ulile, because there isn't another proximity indication than the signal strength and as you have written it depends on many parameters.

Comment: Thanks... however RSSI is not good enough for me since it also depends on the power level of the peripheral device.

Comment: Thats true, but there isn't another possibility